# Encryption with input and output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and am stuck on the task below. Below is an example of my input file and what I want it to output.

Input File Message (from online sample)

```
So pure of heart
And strong of mind
So true of aim with his marshmallow laser
Marshmallow laser
```

Output File Message

```
LhtinkXthYtaXTkm
ugWtlmkhgZthYtfbgW
LhtmknXthYtTbftpbmatabltfTklafTeehpteTlXk
FTklafTeehpteTlXk
```

Below is my syntax and guidance as to why it isn't completing the task intended would be helpful. It is printing 'wwww'....I believe it is a 'w' for each line.

```
inputFileName = input("Enter the message to encrypt: ")
key = int( input("Enter the shift key: " ))
outputFileName = input("Enter the output file name: " )

infile=open(inputFileName,"r")
outfile = open( outputFileName, "w" )

sequence=infile.readlines()

alphabet = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
shiftedAlphabetStart = alphabet[len(alphabet) - key:]
shiftedAlphabetEnd = alphabet[:len(alphabet) - key]
shiftedAlphabet = shiftedAlphabetStart + shiftedAlphabetEnd


print( alphabet )
print( shiftedAlphabet )

encryptedMessage = ''
for character in sequence:
    letterIndex = alphabet.find( character )
    encryptedCharacter = shiftedAlphabet[letterIndex]
    #print( "{0} -> {1}".format( character, encryptedCharacter ) )

    encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage + encryptedCharacter

print( "The encrypted message is: {0}".format( encryptedMessage ))
```

Comment: *Note:* you can just use `string.ascii_letters` instead of writing the whole alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `print(sequence)`, you'll realize that it's a List of lines, not a string.

So when you iterate through it with `for character in sequence:`, you're not iterating through the original text character by character, you're iterating through the list line by line.

This is because `readlines()` return a list of lines.

You can, if you still want to use `readlines()`, try adding something like:

```
original_text = ''

for line in sequence:
    original_text += line
```

A better way however, is to simply change `sequence = infile.readlines()` to `sequence = infile.read()`.

Comment: Thank you, all comments were helpful. This fixed my issue.